# RStudio - Multiple name for one id problem

Tags: r

I have a data frame that look like this (called df1)

| trip_id | station_id | station_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id123 | s01 | A Street |
| id385 | s02 | B Street |
| id332 | s01 | C Street |
| id423 | s01 | A Street |

The problem is there is an inconsistency with the station name column (multiple names for one id) and I want to correct it based on the most popular name used with the same station id. For example, in the table above, all rows with station id = "s01" must have station name = "A Street" (since A Street occurred 2 times and C Street occurred only once).
The result should look like this:

| trip_id | station_id | station_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id123 | s01 | A Street |
| id385 | s02 | B Street |
| id332 | s01 | A Street |
| id423 | s01 | A Street |

All I'm able to do so far is to extract a list of station id with more than 1 name:

`dupl_list <- unique(df1[,c("station_id","station_name")]) %>% group_by (station_id) %>% count() %>% filter(n>1)`
Thx for reading

Comment: I assume you're happy with a tidyverse solution.  Use `slice_max` to identify the most popular `station_name`.  (How will you handle ties?)  Then `left_join` the original data frame with the data frame containing the most popular `station_name`s.

Comment: thx Limey, haven't heard about that I will take a look on that function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using base R you can do this:

```r
# data
df1 <- data.frame(trip_id=c('id123', 'id332', 'id385', 'id423'),
                  station_id=c('s01', 's02', 's01', 's01'),
                  station_name=c('A Street', 'B Street', 'C Street', 'A Street'),
                  date_of_trip=c(1, 1, 3, 2))
# most common name for each id (alphabetically lowest in case of ties)
id.name <- tapply(df1$station_name, df1$station_id, function(x) {
  tab <- table(x)
  names(which.max(tab))
})

df1$station_name <- id.name[df1$station_id]
```

`dplyr` way:

```r
df1 <- df1 %>% 
  group_by(station_id) %>% 
  mutate(station_name = names(which.max(table(station_name))))
```

According to the most recent trip:

```r
df1 <- df1 %>% 
  group_by(station_id) %>% 
  mutate(station_name = station_name[which.max(date_of_trip)])
```

Comment: Solved the problem for me (in fact, after applying your method I found out my df also has duplicated id for the same names, but with variable reverse, I solved it as well). Just one last question, do you have any idea if I want to use, in a 2nd case, the most recent name instead of the most popular one, to popularize the name column? btw I'm kinda new to R so I lost at the tapply part :D

Comment: What determines which name is more recent?

Comment: I forgot to mention, it's another column says, date_of_trip, with date time type already

Comment: Ok, see my updated answer.

Comment: I see the logic, very neat, thx again!

Comment: Great! Please, consider marking the answer as accepted if it helped you ;-)